# Best way to create test methods and avoid soql limits exception

Tags: failing-tests

I have an apex controller which has some really bad code doing a lot of unwanted soqls based on conditions. My current test class has a test method which executes all the apex controller methods in one method and runs into soql limits exception. To avoid the soql limits exception,I would like to know the following. If i create separate test methods in the same test class, will each test method has a maximum of 100 soql calls allowed? Or Should i create a separate test class for each scenario and have independent test methods which would provide me 100 soql calls?
 Underlying question. Does each test method in a test class has a maximum 100 soql calls or each test class irrespective of the test methods in it have a maximum 100 soql calls?

Comment: Each test method has two sets of limits, the second set being for the code within `Test.startTest()` and `Test.stopTest()`

Answer (score 1):

You can write your test methods in the same test class as every test method is independent of the other test method in the same class.Also, You can use Test.startTest and Test.StopTest to check any logic of your controller with limits being applied freshly, within your test method.Refer to the below link for best practices:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_best_practices.htm